# how to push react component inside a mapped array data by index in React JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I was recently working on a react project where I have to display a few items on the page (which would be data from api), and between them, I have to display an advertisement component. is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, do you have any code that I can work with ?

Comment: you should change this question to : how we can show some item elements and an ad between them, not asking if it's possible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can render an array of item elements, and an advertisment element in middle of them.

```
const Ad = () => (<div>ad item</div>)
const List = () => {
let [items, setItems] = useState(['item 1', 'item 2'])
return (
<>
  {
  items.filter((item, index) => index < 6)
    .map((item, index) => (<div>{item.title}</div>))
  }
  {<Ad />}
  {
  items.filter((item, index) => index >= 6)
    .map((item, index) => (<div>{item.title}</div>))
  }
</>
)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think following snippet would help you.

```
const Ad = () => <div> ad item </div>;
const itemsArrays = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const firstSix = itemsArrays.splice(0, 6);

const List = () => {
  let [topItems, setTopItems] = useState(firstSix);
  let [bottomItems, setBottomItems] = useState(itemsArrays);

  return (
    <>
      {topItems.map((item, index) => (
        <div> {item.title} </div>
      ))}{" "}
      <Ad />{" "}
      {bottomItems.map((item, index) => (
        <div> {item.title} </div>
      ))}{" "}
    </>
  );
};
```